# Adding extra IP to NIC causes connectivity issues for main IP (Win Server 2012 / IIS)

Tags: networking, iis, vmware-vsphere

I am experiencing a very odd situation:

I have set up 8 IP addresses in a single NIC (plus it's main IP) for use as a web server - and have 8 websites happily running in IIS8.

(The server in question is a Win2012 VM running in VMware vSphere)

When I come to add a 9th IP, I start experiencing connectivity issues on the server's main IP - IIS cant access the remote SQL server or Progress server (I also cant access the SQL server in SQL Server Management Studio from the server. which suggests its not an IIS related issue)

Therefore 2 of the websites throw errors stating they could not connect to their respective SQL / Progress server.

There are 100% NO IP conflicts, and I have also tried using fresh unused IP's from the pool, but I get the same result.

I didnt think there were any limits on IP addresses in Windows, but could this be VMware related?

Remove the IP and reboot, all is good again...

**Day 2 - Update:**

**So after bashing our heads together all day yesterday and sleeping on it, I decided to add a secondary virtual NIC.** 
**Leaving the 8 working IPs on the first one, and adding the others (currently 3, but will be 8) on the secondary.**

***This works.***

**So where does this point? a VMXNET3 NIC driver issue, a VMware routing issue, a windows server issue... god knows...!**

**Added by request:**
[image]

**and IPCONFIG /ALL**

[image]

Comment: `The server in question is a Win2012 VM running in VMware` - VMware isn't a product, it's a company. Which VMware product are you using? Also, give us some details about the connectivity problem. Telling us `IIS cant access the remote SQL server` doesn't give us any useful information for which we can provide answers. What happens when you try to connect to SQL? What error messages (if any) do you get? What troubleshooting have you done? Etc., etc.

Comment: I believe its vSphere, but will need to check when the network admin comes back in. 

As soon as I enable the 9th IP on the NIC, any website that uses SQL server or Progress (both on separate servers) stops working, giving errors that stare they were unable to connect to their database / content server.
I am also unable to connect to the SQL server via SQL Management studio under these circumstances.

I have spent the whole day narrowing down the cause of the connectivity issues to the act of adding another IP- This is as far as i have got, and am now out of ideas as to what the root cause is.

Comment: "could this be VMware related" - no, ESXi has vSwitches and they're just that - switches, layer 2 devices, so they can't (unless very oddly configured) have anything to do with IP (a layer 3 protocol) - show us the output of 'ipconfig /all' and 'route print'

Comment: Thanks for the 'route print' but it's meaningless without the 'ipconfig /all'

Comment: ipconfig /all added
These are from the WORKING config, If I add another it just slips in there, and looks no different

Comment: Please avoid using screenshots when you can easily copy and paste the same thing.

Comment: I tried @MichaelHampton, but it was an unreadable mess!

Comment: http://serverfault.com/help/formatting

Comment: @DarkcatStudios - put the additional ip address on the server and repost your `route print` and `ipconfig /all` output. I know you've stated that it's the same, but we'd like to see it for ourselves.

Comment: Will do, won't be till tomorrow now as I'm home...